# Deploying C# application that uses DirectX assemblies

Tags: c#, deployment, directx, assemblies

I am developing the application that uses DirectX for graphics rendering. I have to point out that I am not using XNA or SlimDX, although I probably should. However, I did not know this at the project launch, and now it's too late as it would take a lot of time to convert to any of these.

That said, I need to deploy the application to users. In my project, I have referenced the following assemblies:

- Microsoft.DirectX
- Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
- Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX

I only need these assemblies, nothing else. The users are required to have DirectX installed on their computers as a prerequisite. Therefore, I found including these DirectX DLLs to my application folder or GAC unnecessary.

I am having problems with some environments while other work perfectly. I've traced the issue to whether DirectX assemblies are registered in %windir%\assembly. If there are DirectX assemblies listed here, the application runs. If there are not - it fails to launch.

The problem is that even though DirectX is installed on all computers (dxdiag works, DirectX files are listed in it), some of them do not have these assemblies listed in there. When this happens, the application fails with System.IO.FileNotFound exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D, Version=1.0.2902.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

For instance, if the latest stand-alone installer is downloaded from Microsoft website and installed, the assemblies are registered. I am not sure about the case when they do not get installed, but it happens. Often.

My questions:

1. Why does DirectX sometimes register these assemblies and sometimes do not?
2. What is the proper way to reference DirectX assemblies from within
   the application?

Comment: Are they the same assembly versions across machines and your development PC?

Comment: @Adam Actually, I am not sure at all. I am targeting DirectX 9 DLL's that date back to 2005. Some of users are having DirectX 11 installed (which is newer, of course) and the application fails. I assume more recent versions of DirectX should install all previous DLL versions as well, so to allow for application compatibility. If this was not the case, I'd have to reference multiple versions of assemblies. Am I right?

Comment: From DirectX documentation it does look like each version is deployed. Have you thought about including DirectX install in your installation package. As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So even if they had it installed the installation would just quietly disappear, though if they didn't it would install silently then continue on.

Comment: DirectX 11's support for previous versions is down through a virtualization of sorts.  If your program requires DirectX 9 then require that version, supply the version you built against on your support website, and tell users to install that version.  Why are you not building against Direct X 11?

Comment: Have you tried executing the DirectX Web-Setup? It downloads missing or older DLLs. Maybe it registers the DLLs in the GAC too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not surprised that you're seeing these issues. You're relying on an extremely old, discontinued, and no-longer-supported API. The latest runtime installers will still install the assemblies for compatibility purposes, but they're not included by default because they don't expect anyone to use them.

Honestly, they're really old (like, 10 years old), they have numerous known bugs and issues that will *never* be fixed, and there are perfectly acceptable replacements out there. You should either switch to one of them or resign yourself to dealing with issues like this for as long as you continue to support your app.

Comment: Are you saying that installing the assemblies is only done by offline runtime installer and is obsolete? Because that would match the pattern I'm experiencing on client computers. As I already stated, I'm aware that using Managed DirectX is not supported anymore, but was hoping that I would still be able to use it (I'm really not using any advanced DirectX techniques, just a plain 2D rendering). If you're right, running the offline installer would have to be mandatory on client computers.

Comment: I don't know for sure, since it's been a long time since I've used it. Best way to find out is to set up a quick VM and run the various installers and check to see which ones install the managed DLLs.

Comment: While your answer does not solve my problem, it is very much obvious that you are right and that I should not be using obsolete libraries. Thanks for making me realize this. PS. Assemblies are installed only by offline installer.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced something similar with the SimConnect DLL that is part of Flight Simulator. In this case it turned out that the DLL was not added to the GAC if a user installed Flight Simulator before they installed the .Net framework.

My guess is that something similar is happening here.

This of course means that it could only occur on XP systems that do not have .Net by default and it should be fixed after a reinstall of DX after .Net has been installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue occurs on Windows 7 as well. You're right, .NET is installed by default on this system, so this cannot be the source of the problem in my case. Thanks for the insight, though.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and the only logic solution is to install Directx, @Daniel-van-os is right. This will definitely resolve the problem, but Directx has compatibility issues and the main problem is that my software will be installed in many PCs and adding Directx as a prerequisite is not an option. So good bye Directx, I will see another solution for sure :).